# Python - OAUTH2 How to get access token using PCKE?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, openid, pkce

I am trying to get this access token with Python. With Postman I can get an access token. After configurations in the screenshots, I click the Get Access Token button, and A pop-up throws for username and password. Then I fill them. After that, I can get an access token from Postman.

[image: Postman config 1]

[image: Postman config 2]

To get an access token with Python, I wrote the code below. In the first get request, I get the cookies and Redirect URL(to post user credentials). Then, I post user credentials and cookies to Redirected URL. After that, the response header["location"] must include a code parameter to get the token. But, the header parameter does not have a code parameter. It has an Authorization URL with query parameters. **How can get this code parameter?** Finally, I will post a request(to token URL) with this code to get an access token on the response body.

```
import base64
import hashlib
import json
import os
import re
import urllib.parse
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from rich import print

username = 'username '
password = 'password '
client_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
client_secret = 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy'
prod_url = 'https://url:port'
callback_url = prod_url + '/main/ifsapplications/projection/oauth2/callback'
authorization_url = prod_url + '/openid-connect-provider/idp/authorization'
token_url = prod_url + '/openid-connect-provider/idp/token'
code_challenge_method = "S256" #SHA-256
scope = 'openid'
response_type ='code'
#Add auth data to request headers
#Grant type = authorization code with pkce
#send client credentials in body

code_verifier = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(os.urandom(40)).decode('utf-8')
code_verifier = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', '', code_verifier)
code_challenge = hashlib.sha256(code_verifier.encode('utf-8')).digest()
code_challenge = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(code_challenge).decode('utf-8')
code_challenge = code_challenge.replace('=', '')
resp = requests. Get(
    url=authorization_url,
    params={
        "response_type": response_type,
        "client_id": client_id,
        "scope": scope,
        "redirect_uri": callback_url,
        "code_challenge": code_challenge,
        "code_challenge_method": code_challenge_method,
    },
    allow_redirects=False
)
cookie = resp.headers['Set-Cookie']
cookie = '; '.join(c.split(';')[0] for c in cookie. Split(', '))

soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')
form_action = soup. Find('a').text

resp = requests. Post(
    url=form_action, 
    data={
        "username": username,
        "password": password
    }, 
    headers={"Cookie": cookie,
             "Referer": form_action},
    allow_redirects=False
)

redirect = resp.headers['Location']

print(resp.text)
print(resp.headers)
```

OUTPUT:
[image: Output]